# Processes that converge to the Pareto distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, pareto-distribution

Do any stochastic processes generate the Pareto distribution as the steady-state statistic of the ensemble?

For example,

$$
dS_t = f(t, S_t, W_t)
$$

where in the Ito sense the p.d.f. of $ g(S_t) $ is Pareto and $ g(\cdot) $ is one-to-one.

Comment: Maybe you could give a diffusion as a (better known) possible Stochastic Differential Equation? Diffusions with a given stationary distribution could be appealing here. The `extreme-value` tag seems relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I was after, but moving closer.

Let $ R $ be a random variable, then the p.d.f of $ v = R^t $ is given by,

$$\begin{align}
\rho_v &= \int dR ~ \rho_R ~ \delta(v - R^t) \\
  &= \frac{\rho_R(v^{1/t})}{t v^{(t-1)/t}} ~~ \forall t > 0
\end{align}$$

which is a [Power-law probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_law#Power-law_probability_distributions).

For $ t \rightarrow \infty $,

$$
\rho_v \propto \frac{1}{v}
$$